# The type 'XXX' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following classes

```
public interface IHtmlString
{
    string ToHtmlString();
}

public class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>, IHtmlString
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }
    public T Method1()
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
    public T Method2(string key, object value)
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return ToString();
    }
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass<DerivedClassA>
{
    public DerivedClassA MethodSpecificToClassA()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "<div/>";            
    }
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass<DerivedClassB>
{
    public DerivedClassB MethodSpecificToClassB()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "<span/>";
    }
}
```

Note that the method returns `this` instance so that i can chain methods, like below

```
 var a = new DerivedClassA()
        .Method1()
        .MethodSpecificToClassA()
        .ToHtmlString();
```

However im getting compile time error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0311  The type 'DerivedClassA' cannot be
>   used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'BaseClass'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'DerivedClassA' to
>   'System.Web.IHtmlString'. WebApplication5 C:\MyProjects\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Models\BaseBuilder.cs 27  Active

How do i refactor these classes so i have `IHtmlString` interface on base class only?

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
public class BaseClass<T> : IHtmlString where T : BaseClass<T>
{
}
```